# Python: Create two lists from loop and sum both

Tags: python, cs50

I'm working on a credit project of CS50 and I have some problem with the verification of the credit card.

Here the function I create:

```
def main():

while True :
    cardnumber = input("Please enter a credit card number: ")
    if cardnumber.isdecimal() and int(cardnumber) > 0 :
        break

count = len(cardnumber)

if count != 13 and count != 15 and count != 16:
    print("INVALID")
else:
    check(count, cardnumber)


def check(length, number):

lenght_max = 15

if length == 15 and int(number[0]) == 3 and (int(number[1]) == 4 or int(number[1]) == 7):
    if validator(number):
        print("AMEX")
elif length == 16 and int(number[0]) == 5 and int(number[1]) <= 5:
    if validator(number):
        print("MASTERCARD")
elif length == 16 or length == 13 and int(number[0]) == 4:
    if validator(number):
        print("VISA")
else:
    print("INVALID")
return number


def validator(num):

sum = 0
while num > 0:
    sum += num % 10
    num = num // 10

return sum
odd = [int(num[i]) * 2 for i in range(1, len(num), 2)]
even = [int(num[i]) for i in range(0, len(num), 2)]

new_sum = sum(validator(x) for x in odd) + sum(even)
if(new_sum % 10 == 0):
    return True
else:
    print("INVALID")

main()
```

I found the way to print the evens and the odds(multiply also time 2) but now I have to sum booth and check if the remainder is 0

[image]

Here the complete instruction:
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/credit/credit.html

Comment: What you have are lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a helper function to sum your digits. You'll need to use it extensively.

```
def dig_sum(num):
   sum = 0
   while num > 0:
      sum += num % 10
      num = num // 10

   return sum

num = '378282246310005' # your credit card number
odd = [int(num[i]) * 2 for i in range(1, len(num), 2)] # these two remain the same
even = [int(num[i]) for i in range(0, len(num), 2)]

new_sum = sum(dig_sum(x) for x in odd) + sum(even)
if(new_sum % 10 == 0):
    print('Valid') #valid!
```

`sum(dig_sum(x) for x in odd)` will get the digit sum for each number in your `odd` list and `sum(...)` that finds the resultant sum.

Input:

```
'378282246310005'
```

Output:

```
Valid
```

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't have any issues with Willem getting his answer accepted, but you really shouldn't vacillate when accepting an answer. It's a bit unfair to everyone involved.

Comment: sorry but I'm really new and I don't understand really well how works some things in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Sebastiano The goal is to ask good questions, provide good answers to good questions, and accept answers that help you the most. :) Cheers.

Comment: I just have an error with the implementation, could you please clear me why?
I update the code

Comment: Sorry. I gave you an incorrect paste. pastebin.com/raw/6abd3xNx

Comment: I don't understand why but it seems that the function doesn't work very well. 
I mean... for some number works and for another not.
btw I'll check with some math these number and see whit the function the result.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: @Sebastiano It isn't clear what the exact issue is. Could you open a new question with your current state of code and a reproducible example?

Comment: @Sebastiano Read THIS: "_Test out your program with a whole bunch of inputs, both valid and invalid. (We certainly will!) Here are a few card numbers that PayPal recommends for testing:..._" Some of those numbers are SUPPOSED to be invalid.

Comment: sorry my fault :(

Answer (score 1):

A first problem with your function is that you do **not store the even/odd digits** somewhere: you construct a list with one element each time, and print that element.

Now since two times a digit, can only result in a two digit number, we can use:

```
def sum2(x):
    return (2*x)//10 + (2*x)%10
```

You can construct a *list* of *all* the digits at odd index with:

```
odd = [int(number[i]) for i in range(1,length,2)]
```

The same for digits at even index:

```
even = [int(number[i]) for i in range(0,length,2)]
```

Now we can simply use the **`sum(..)` builtin** function to sum up the digits:

```
total = sum(sum2(oddi) for oddi in odd) + sum(even)
```

and check if it is a multiple of 10:

```
return total%10 == 0
```

Or putting it all together:

```
def validator(number, length):
    odd = [int(number[i]) for i in range(1,length,2)]
    even = [int(number[i]) for i in range(0,length,2)]
    total = sum(sum2(oddi) for oddi in odd) + sum(even)
    return total%10 == 0
```

Or we can use a the following one liner for experts:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def validator(number,length):
    numbi = iter(numbi)
    return sum(x+sum2(y) for x,y in zip_longest(numbi,numbi,fillvalue=0))%10 == 0
```

Comment: With `sum(odd) * 2`, you're not accounting for the sum of digits, I think?

Comment: If `odd = [7, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0]`, OP would want the sum of the sum of digits of `odd[i] * 2` to be 27. Your code gives 36.

Comment: thank you very much, I've just to adapt a bit for the whole function that I use but it definitely works :)

@Coldspeed you are right, I have to modify the *2 in odd and not in the total

Comment: @Coldspeed: The sum of elements times two is equal to two times the sum of the elements. Or more formal `a*(b+c) == a*b + a*c`.

Comment: `>>> n = '378282246310005'
>>> validator(n, len(n))
False` ? (For OP's input which should return `True`)

Comment: Thanks for taking my feedback seriously! I've seen people who are least bothered to correct their mistakes.